# Condition to obtain a not compact embedding

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, compactness, embeddings

I have the two spaces $W_0^{1,p}$ with the norme $$||u||^p=||u||^p_{L^p}+||\nabla u||^p_{L^p}$$ and $$L^{p^*}_{\alpha}=\{ u~\text{measurable}, \int_{\Omega} (|x|^{\alpha} u(x)|)^{p^*} dx<\infty\}$$ equiped with the norm $$||u||_{L^{p^*}_{\alpha}}^{p^*}=\int_{\Omega} (|x|^{\alpha}|u(x)|)^{p^*} dx$$

How to find the condition on $\alpha>0$ such that $W^{1,p}_0$ do not be compactly embeded in $L^{p^*}_{\alpha}$ ?

Where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is bounded,  $N>p$ and $p^*=\frac{Np}{N-p}$

Thank you

Comment: Maz'ja's book on Sobolev spaces has compactness results for weighted  Sobolev spaces. See  Sec 1.4.6 of  his book *Sobolev Spaces with Applications to Elliptic Partial Differential Equations*, 2nd Edition, Springer Verlag, 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure of the compactness of the embedding $W^{1, p} (\Omega) \subset L^{p^*} (\Omega)$ is local, that is, it can be exhibited in any ball.

An abstract way of seeing the failure of the embedding is to consider a ball $B$ such that $\overline{B} \subset \Omega \setminus \{0\}$. The compactness of the embedding of $W^{1, p} (\Omega)$ in $L^{p^*}_\alpha (\Omega)$ would then imply the compactness of the embedding of $W^{1, p} (B)$ in the unweighted space $L^{p^*} (B)$, in contradiction with the classical theory.

Alternatively, fix a point $a \in \Omega$ and a test function $\varphi \in C^1_c (\mathbb{R}^N)$, and define 
$$
  \varphi_{\lambda} (x) = \lambda^{1-\frac{N}{p}} \varphi \Bigl(\frac{x - a}{\lambda}\Bigr).
$$
There exists $\lambda_0>0$ such that if $\lambda \in (0, \lambda_0)$, then $\varphi_\lambda \in C^1_c (\Omega) \subset W^{1,p} (\Omega)$. Moreover the family $(\varphi_\lambda)_{\lambda \in (0, \lambda_0)}$ is bounded in $W^{1, p} (\Omega)$ but is not relatively compact in $L^{p^*}_\alpha (\Omega)$.

Comment: What i the condition on $\alpha$ ? thank you

Comment: There is no condition on $\alpha$.

Comment: This means that $W^{1,p}_0$ is not compactly embeded in any space $L^{p^*}_{\alpha}$ right ?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: Can you give me more details why $(\varphi_{\lambda})$ is not relatively compact ? what about if we replace $p^*$ by any $q>p$ ? thank you

Comment: It converges almost everywhere to \(0\) as \(\lambda \to 0\), whereas its norm does not converge to \(0\).

Comment: I proved that there is a compact injection between $W^{1,p}_0$ and $C_{\theta}=\{u\in C(\overline{\Omega}), \sup (|x|^{\theta} |u(x)|)<\infty\}$ for $\theta>\frac{N}{p}$ and there is a continuous injection between $C_{\theta}$ and $L^{p^*}_{\theta}$ so where is the contradiction ?

Comment: I think that we have this when $\lambda$ goes to $+\infty$ not near $0$ look at $1-\frac{N}{p}$ it is negative

Comment: Please give me an answer how we prove the weak convergence ?

Comment: The week convergence comes from the fact that the sequence is bounded in norm and converges almost everywhere as $\lambda \to 0$.

Comment: but why it is bounded please, why convergence almost every where imply the weak convergence >

Comment: also we have that $||v_{\lambda}||_{L^{p^*}_{\alpha}}=||v||_{L^{p^*}_{\alpha}}$ if and only if $\alpha =0$ impossible !

Comment: please explain me how you find that $v_{\lambda}$ do not converge to 0 in $L^{p^*}_{\alpha}$